# Close HTTP port on Heroku

Tags: security, heroku, ws-security

Is it possible to close the HTTP port for an application hosted on Heroku? I want to enforce basic auth over HTTPS.

NOTE: Redirect is not an option. I don't want to do a redirect because the HTTP basic auth credentials will have already been transmitted in the clear. I really want to stop the connection from being stablished in the first place.

If not possible, what other options would I have?

Thanks